# Negative value for categories axis in highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I have x axis of type category and the series contains negative x values for that axis. How can I bind the point in with negative x values to match category, so it can be displayed the correct category to that point?
I tried max and min it didn't help much.

http://jsfiddle.net/nabilasbi/kcj9qxLu/

Ps. The same problem happens with y axis with negative y values.

```
   xAxis: {

        "categories": [
            "-1 - Negative",

            "2 - High",
            "3 - Moderate",
            "4 - Low"],
            "type": "category"
    },
    series: [{
        data: [
            [-1, 4, 87],
            [2, -1, 73],
            [1, 4, 42],
            [1, 3, 79],
            [2, 3, 60],
            [3, 2, 58],
            [4, 2, 56]
        ]
    }]
```

Comment: You can also use label formatter and then return names like here (http://jsfiddle.net/kcj9qxLu/2/) obviously you need to adapt logic

Comment: Thanks, but does this work for category axis ?

Comment: The categories are only strings, but in data you have numbers. There is no module which map one data into second one. So I introduce you how use numbers and return names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the categories field is an array, which is 0-based, I think your only option is to transpose your data so that it, too, is 0-based. You can then modify the "name" of the data item to show the accurate value.

[Bubble Chart - Name](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series<bubble>.data.name).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if intended or not, but I discovered that if you pass an object with numeric keys (or an array with negative key properties added) as categories, it will work just fine.

```
"categories": {
            "-1": "-1 - Negative",

            "2": "2 - High",
            "3": "3 - Moderate",
            "4": "4 - Low"}
```

See it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/j1pvLqc6/